# Wordpress .htaccess - route other URLs to another app

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, htaccess

I need help in WordPress `.htaccess`. My projects name is **Project** this is WordPress and onepage website, inside this I have one more project that is built in CI named **app**. What I want is, if someone enters anything after `/`, then get content from CI `App` project. I do not want to redirect user to `http://example.com/app/<anything>`.  As i said wordpress project is one page, so when i click on navigations i got `!#` like characters in url.

```
http://example.com/<anything>
```

My current .htaccess is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since your WordPress site is just a one-page site, this is served from the single URL `http://example.com/`. You then want `http://example.com/<something>` to be internally rewritten to `http://example.com/app/<something>`.

You can add the following mod_rewrite directives *before* your existing WordPress directives (ie. WordPress front-controller) in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
# Route all URL-paths (of 1 or more characters) to CI app
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.+) /app/$1 [L]

# WordPress directives start here...
:
```

The `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that only initial requests are rewritten, as opposed to internal rewrites to `index.php` by WordPress.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `(.+)` ensures we only match URL-paths longer than one character, missing the document root - which is passed through to WordPress.

Comment: not working, got `object not found`